# Invoking child lambda function from parent lambda function - parent lambda returning empty string

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a child lambda function which I can invoke successfully from the parent and get a 200 status code but the parent lambda gets an empty string despite the fact the the child lambda is returning the expected data. I am fairly new to python, so I am sure it is something simple that I'm missing.

Child Lambda

```
# empty data dict as this can change in the function due to various conditions
data{}

# populate data dict for returned payload
                data["first_string"] = 'first'
                data["second_string"] = 'second'
                data["first_number"] = 100

# this is what the child lambda returns and what expect to get when I invoke from the parent lambda
return json.dumps(data)
```

Child lambda output is as expected. See below.

```
"{\"first_string\": \"first\", \"second_string\": \"second\", \"first_number\": 100}"
```

Parent lambda

```
response = Lambda_client.invoke(
            FunctionName='lambda-function-arn',
            InvocationType='RequestResponse',
            Payload=json.dumps(input_params),
            LogType='Tail'
        )

response_payload = response['Payload'].read().decode("utf-8")
print("This is the response from the child lambda" + response_payload)
```

Parent lambda response_payload is an empty string. When I print it (as above) I get...

> This is the response from the child lambda"{}"

It should contain the output from the child lambda. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your "Child Lambda" code is totally incorrect. What is the actual, full code of your function?

Comment: I couldn't post the entire child lambda function, it's too long. The child lambda function returns what it is supposed to return when I test it independently. I just can't get the output when  I try to invoke it from the parent function.

I will update to post a scaled down version of both lambda functions in the morning for further clarity.

Comment: Did you verify that your function actually works, and does not result in an error when you invoke it from parent?

Comment: It doesn't return an error. Just a status 200 and an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in your code is working correctly. I have created two Python 3.9 lambda functions. And the parent lambda is getting the correct response.

Things to try:

1. Check that the ARN of the child lambda doesn't have an old version that returns "{}". And that you are not invoking that version. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-versions.html)
2. Check that you are not emptying the dict depending on some input values
3. Create two new lambdas and try copying my code directly

---

parent lambda

```
import json
import boto3

Lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    inputParams = {}
 
    response = Lambda_client.invoke(
                FunctionName='arn',
                InvocationType='RequestResponse',
                Payload=json.dumps(inputParams),
                LogType='Tail'
            )
    
    print(response)
    response_payload = response['Payload'].read().decode("utf-8")
    print("This is the response from the child lambda" + response_payload)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('This is the parent lambda')
    }
```

child lambda

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    data = {}
    
    data["first_string"] = 'first'
    data["second_string"] = 'second'
    data["first_number"] = 100

    return json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. :-) I will try your suggestions this morning.

Comment: Цветан Иванов -It ended up being an error in one of the permissions to a service I was using in the child lambda that I defined in the lambda function's CloudFormation template. I was so sure it was a problem with the way I was invoking the child function that I missed it. Dumb. :-) I have marked yours as the answer because it was the "sanity check" that helped me track down the real problem. :-)